# how do I add a test web service to my project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, web-services

I have a test web service replicating a live web service that hasn't been made public yet (It will be public when the app is released).

I added a new ASP.NET Web Service Application to my solution. Now when I try and add a web reference from the main project and choose "Browse To Web services in this solution" it doesn't find the test web service.

Am I missing an important step here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the webservice you're trying to connect to isn't running . Do an F5, verify that the service has started by checking the address in the browser then try to add the refference again.

If it doesn't work, just specify the address by hand.

Comment: Interesting, I assumed Visual Studio would look through the solution and pick up any web services that had been defined.